# Drupal jQuery dependency throws error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: jquery, drupal, theming

I am pretty new to Drupal (8) and it's templating system. I set up a themename.libraries.yml and a themename.info.yml that look like this:

xxx.info.yml:

```
    name: xxx
    description: theme for xxx
    type: theme
    core: 8.x
    package: Custom
    basetheme: classy
    libraries:
      - xxx/stylesheets
      - xxx/javascript
    regions:  
      content: Content
      pagetitle: Pagetitle
      searchblock: Searchblock
```

xxx.libraries.yml

```
    stylesheets:
      css:
        theme:
          css/style.css: {}
          https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans: {}
          https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat: {}
    javascript:
      js:
          js/site.js: {}
          js/sticky.js: {}
```

This works pretty fine, just like I want it. But when I log out, core-jQuery isn't loaded. So I found out, I have to add:

```
 dependencies:
          - core/jquery: {}
```

to make Drupal integrate jQuery for anonymous users. But every time I add the lines dependencies: - core/jquery: {} and clear the cache, The whole site breaks and returns a white screen with:

**"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- core/jquery: {}` should just be `- core/jquery`
Here is an example:

```
my_awsome_module:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/my_awesome_module.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried both - with and without {}. I found out later, I just had the wrong spaces in YAML.